# How to create a path and extract data from it using python?

Tags: python, abaqus

I am performing a simulation in Abaqus that consists of the impact of two plates. Imagine that the simulation has 100 frames, what I want is to extract data along a path for a specific frame. I wrote this Python script to extract the velocity and mises data from all the nodes for all frames (the txt file is gigantic), but I want to do it for just a set at a given frame. Does anyone know how to create a node set or path, and then extract the data along this set or path for a certain frame?

Script to export data from abaqus:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from numpy import savetxt
import math
from odbAccess import *
from textRepr import *
import os, sys
#import matplotlib.pyplot

start_time = time.time()
path = (os.getcwd())
odbName = '%s/Job-1.odb'%path
odb = openOdb(odbName, readOnly=True)
myAssembly = odb.rootAssembly.instances['FIXED-1']
newpath = 'results'
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)
steps1 = odb.steps['Step-1'].frames
currentframe1 = []

for c_elem in range(len(steps1)):
    currentframe1 = steps1[c_elem]
    mises = []
    velocity = []
    strain = []
    displacement = []
    fieldvalues_mises = currentframe1.fieldOutputs['S']
    fieldvalues_velocity = currentframe1.fieldOutputs['V']
    fieldvalues_displacement = currentframe1.fieldOutputs['U']
    fieldvalues_strain = currentframe1.fieldOutputs['LE']
    vel_set = fieldvalues_velocity.values
    disp_set = fieldvalues_displacement.values
    mises_set = fieldvalues_mises.values
    strain_set = fieldvalues_strain.values
    for v in vel_set:
        velocity.append(v.data)
    for s in strain_set:
        strain.append(s.data)
    for m in mises_set:
        mises.append(m.data)
    for d in disp_set:
        displacement.append(d.data)

# Vector of frames
vector_frame = c_elem*[1]

with open('velocityFile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(1,len(vector_frame)+1):
        f.write('\n\n')
        for j in velocity:
            f.write(str(j) + 3*' ')
        

with open('misesFile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(1,len(vector_frame)+1):
        f.write('\n\n')
        for j in mises:
            f.write(str(j) + 3*' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you open the odb as editable? The default is read only and you CANNOT save something in it, so your line won't be there. This is why abaqus will always tell you that local outputs are only stored in the current session.

Also cathing up on your code snippet, you cannot simply use the name but have to create set in the odb e.g.

```
odb.rootAssembly.nodeSets['LINE_1']
```

and use this set in region.
The set has to be present in the assembly.

Comment: This is technically answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Open the `odb` as editable, create a path of interest and save it in the odb. Use the script to read the variables of interest using the created path. Have a look at `Viewing results along a path` in the documentation for path creation and obtaining xy results.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I don't know how to doing. While doing the simulation (before post-processing), I create a node set called LINE_1. But then, when I wanted to get the coordinates of this set for a given frameI used the form: resultCoord = steps1[6].fieldOutputs["COORD"].getSubset(region=LINE_1).values. And it gave me a error message saying that the LINE_1 did not exist. Therefore, I think the best way is to create the node set or path in the python script and then extract the data. Do you know how to do it this way? Thank you